# How to take a whole layout with its contents to the right of the design panel?

Tags: android-layout, alignment, chat, android-relativelayout, right-align

I am trying to make a chat app, for this I need a sender chat bubble and receiver chat bubble. Since receiver chat bubble stays in left of the screen, it's not the problem. But the sender chat bubble needs to be in completely right to the screen.
I used Relative Layout and used **android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"** but the problem is, it does take all of its contents right but the space is still there. The picture will clear most of it-
[image: Relative Layout]

As you can see here, the space of the left is still there. So whenever I use this layout as the content of an itemview of a recyclerview, if I click to the invisible left place of the itemview/sender chat bubble, it works, but is shouldn't work because the chat bubble content is actually in the right. The question is how to take the whole layout in the right and use it as a chat bubble? I hope I made some sense. The full XML code is below-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/cons"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/sender_design"
        android:maxWidth="400dp"
        android:maxHeight="330dp"
        android:minWidth="100dp"
        android:minHeight="50dp">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/msg2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:inputType="textLongMessage|textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
            android:maxWidth="330dp"
            android:maxHeight="290dp"
            android:text="Hello, I am Baymax."
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/sender_time"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guideline_hori"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline_ver"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline_hori" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sender_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:text="06:00AM"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline_ver" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline_ver"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_end="16dp" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline_hori"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="5dp" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/react1"
        android:layout_width="18dp"
        android:layout_height="18dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/cons"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/cons"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_like" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

I did use other layouts like Linear Horizontal Layout but it still keeps the invisible left space which isn't supposed to be there. I am out of options here.

Comment: So, your problem is not with the space, which should be there, but that the space is clickable? You only want the area to the right to be clickable. On which view are you setting the click listener?

Comment: Exactly, I just want that chat bubble to be clickable but seems like the space is the part of that chat bubble, I mean the layout of that thing. The space is invisible to the user of course but it's clickable. I was using Recycler View since it is a chat app.

Comment: OK. Where are you setting the click listener? Look where you are either creating or binding the view holder for the _RecyclerView_.

Comment: I was setting the click listener to the holder.itemview, means the whole layout. But for that problem I had to set onClickListener to the textview (message itself). Then it works without the space but the message is not supposed to be clicked. the whole chat bubble supposed to be clicked.

Comment: Set the click listener on the layout that contains the _TextView_. You may also nee to set `android:clickable="true"` for that layout.

Comment: Wow! It worked. Make your comment an answer, I will set it accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the click listener on the layout that contains the *TextView*. You may also need to set `android:clickable="true"` for that layout.

Touch events bubble up from the underlying layout to the overlaid child views. The idea is to capture the click event before the child views see it.